# .NET, Topshelf service, Mono and different build machines

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, mono, centos6

I experience a problem with running my .NET application service built with [TopShelf](https://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on Mono.

**The development setup is:** Win 8.1, VS 2015, .NET 4.5.2 as a target framework

**The CI setup:** Win Server 2012, TeamCity 9.1.6, both server and build agent are running at the same machine

**The execution (test server) setup:** CentOS 6 x86_64, Mono 4.2.2

So I've implemented an application running as both a console application and background service (with the TopShelf) and successfully debugged and tested it locally.

I've set up the CI server in the way it builds an application on a build agent and produces as a folder with multiple dlls and .exe runner file inside (Release configuration) as a output. Finally CI publishes this folder to the remote CentOS server.

When I connect to the CentOS server via ssh and try to run it with the `mono myapp.exe` command, I get an error:

```
# mono myapp.exe
Configuration Result:
[Success] Name myapp
[Success] DisplayName myapp
[Success] Description myapp
[Success] ServiceName myapp
Topshelf v3.3.154.0, .NET Framework v4.0.30319.17020
[DEBUG][2/4/2016 7:42:57 PM][Thread 0001][EventStream] StandardOutLogger started
[INFO][2/4/2016 7:42:57 PM][Thread 0006][[akka://AkkaGrid/system/log1-NLogLogger]] NLogLogger started
[DEBUG][2/4/2016 7:42:57 PM][Thread 0001][EventStream(AkkaGrid)] Logger log1-NLogLogger [NLogLogger] started
[DEBUG][2/4/2016 7:42:57 PM][Thread 0001][EventStream(AkkaGrid)] StandardOutLogger being removed
2016-02-04 22:42:57.4509 DEBUG Start
2016-02-04 22:42:57.4538 DEBUG Logger log1-NLogLogger [NLogLogger] started
2016-02-04 22:42:57.4714 DEBUG StandardOutLogger being removed
2016-02-04 22:42:57.4714 DEBUG Default Loggers started
The myapp service is now running, press Control+C to exit.
2016-02-04 22:42:57.5075 ERROR Error while creating actor instance of type MyApp.Actors.Supervisor with 0 args: ()EXCEPTION OCCURRED:Akka.Actor.ActorInitializationException Exception during creation Void Create(System.Exception)
TypeLoadException Error while creating actor instance of type MyApp.Actors.Supervisor with 0 args: () Akka.Actor.ActorBase NewActor()
TargetInvocationException Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. System.Object InternalInvoke(System.Object, System.Object[])
MissingMethodException Method 'Array.Empty' not found.
2016-02-04 22:42:57.5216 INFO Message FetchEntityMessage from NoSender to akka://AkkaGrid/user/$b was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.
```

Ignoring the fact that there are also Akka.net and NLogger inside, the core issue seems to be in this line:

```
MissingMethodException Method 'Array.Empty' not found.
```

So, in order to test the compatibility of my code with Mono itself I've manually copied the application folder (Release) from my local machine (right after VS2015/MsBuild) to CentOS server and ran `mono myapp.exe` command again.
This way the execution succeeded and produced no errors in the output.

To ensure that the issue is not connected to the copying process, I've connected to the Win2012 server (with CI running on it), went to the build agent's working directory and executed `myapp.exe` as a simple windows console application. It ran successfully. Then I copied the application folder manually to the CentOS server via `scp` command from `git bash` and... got the same issue as above.

To provide some extra details, the build log is the following:

```
Step 2/7: Build .NET subsystem (MSBuild) (6s)
[22:36:32][Step 2/7] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\17605015421235b0 "/msbuildPath:C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe"
[22:36:32][Step 2/7] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\17605015421235b0
[22:36:33][Step 2/7] .net\MyApp.sln.teamcity: Build target: TeamCity_Generated_Build (4s)
[22:36:33][.net\MyApp.sln.teamcity] TeamCity_Generated_Build (4s)
[22:36:33][Step 2/7] MSBuild command line parameters contain "/property:" or "/p:". It is recommended to define System Property on Build Parameters instead.
[22:36:38][Step 2/7] Process exited with code 0
```

So I can see that TeamCity doesn't run the MSBuild directly, but some MsBuildBootstrap application. MSBuild Tools 2015 are set in the build step settings. So... that's all the details, any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

> MissingMethodException Method 'Array.Empty' not found.

This method is new in .NET 4.6 as specified in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906179(v=vs.110).aspx).

The problem is that Mono 4.2.2 is not compatible with this version of .NET.

I've looked at the sources, and it looks that Mono from the master branch [already includes this](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/27f07c8095e50cc8be3c5155fcc929a119267db0). However, the commit in which it was introduced is not yet marked as being present in any tag or branch. That means you will have to wait until Mono 4.3 or 4.4 is released, or compile Mono from sources yourself, or maybe try to look for a weekly/nightly build that you could use.

An easier fix may be trying to depend on binaries that are not so bleeding edge (i.e. that were compiled using the framework version 3.5 or 4.0).

Comment: It would be appropriate in case I use .net 4.6. But the target framework is 4.5.2 for all the projects in solution (as described in Q above)

Comment: in the MSDN documentation it says `Available since 4.6`..., maybe you're linking to a dependency that depends on 4.6

Comment: you're right. I also found an information about this issue in .NET 4.6 running on Mono.
But at the same time I checked and double checked that the target framework is still 4.5.2 for the whole solution. Also you most likely know that you can't reference 4.6-only project from 4.5-project as it will fail during compilation process.
Also, the same source code is compiled and runned on mono like a charm when building on my local Win8.1 x64 + VS2015 machine

Comment: You can't add a reference to a 4.6 dll from a 4.5.2, yes, but nothing stops you from changing it after adding the reference, check again if any of the dll's is for fw 4.6 as knocte is right, that method is only on fw 4.6, don't look on your projects, look at the referenced external libraries, nuget packages, etc

Comment: try to add manually a reference to them on a 4.5.2 project. Or use something like Jetbrains DotPeek

Comment: @Gusman well, that could work. Will return with details in some time